# saving dataframe output to multiple folders

Tags: r, url

Pardon my newbieness, but I feel like I've arrived at my wit's end.

I have a (spatial polygon) dataframe (`tri.extract`) that houses all of my data. Every row in this dataframe corresponds to an image. Every image in the dataframe corresponds to a parcel and thus has an attribute `parcel_id`, which denotes which parcel does the image belong to. I wish to save all the images in sub-folders so that each image is in the folder of its respective parcel.

```
parcels <- data.frame(unique(tri.extract@data$parcel_id))
save.dir <- "/home/iordamo/Documents/GIS_Workload/bbox/DemoGrasslandTIMED_END_ImagesMapillary/"

#create sub-folders named after parcel_ids
for (i in 1:nrow(parcels)){
     dir.create(paste0(save.dir,parcels[i,]))
     }

#the save loop itself
for (i in 1:nrow(tri.extract@data)){

  #generate URLs for each image in the dataframe
  img_url<-paste0('https://d1cuyjsrcm0gby.cloudfront.net/',
                  tri.extract@data$key[i],
                  '/thumb-2048.jpg')

  #create a dataframe of all the folder names within save.dir - the parcels 
  dirs.to.save1 <- data.frame(list.files(save.dir, recursive = F))
  dirs.to.save1[] <- lapply(dirs.to.save1, as.character)

  for (g in 1:nrow(dirs.to.save1)){
    if (g==1){
      row <- dirs.to.save1[g,]
      #print(row)
      img_path <- file.path(paste0(save.dir,row, "/"), paste0("i_",tri.extract@data$key[i], ".jpg"))
      download.file(img_url, img_path, quiet=TRUE, mode="wb")
      #next
    }

    else if (g>1){
      row <- dirs.to.save1[g,]
      #print(row)
      img_path <- file.path(paste0(save.dir,row, "/"), paste0("i_",tri.extract@data$key[i], ".jpg"))
      download.file(img_url, img_path, quiet=TRUE, mode="wb")
      #next
    }

  }
}
```

With the code in its current form all of the images get saved in all of the sub-folders. Can anyone explain why? To my understanding I am looping through each record of the dataframe (`tri.extract`), generating a URL, then (in the first nested loop) loop through each parcel and create a `file.path` from the `save.dir` and each row in the `dirs.to.save1` dataframe and the respective image id (`tri.extract@data$key[i]`). And this should output in each respective folder because I am looping through them in the nested loop. Can someone explain to me where my logic fails to be translated to execution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, that wasn't too hard.

Solution turned out be, as usual, simpler than what I originally conjured up:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(tri.extract@data)){

  img_url<-paste0('https://d1cuyjsrcm0gby.cloudfront.net/',
                  tri.extract@data$key[i],
                  '/thumb-2048.jpg')

  for (g in 1:nrow(parcels)){
    row <- droplevels(parcels[g,])
    if(tri.extract@data$parcel_id[i] == parcels[g,]) {
      img_path <- file.path(paste0(save.dir,row), paste0("i_",tri.extract@data$key[i], ".jpg"))
      download.file(img_url, img_path, quiet=TRUE, mode="wb")
    }}
}
```